# php- setting curl timeout to infinity?

Tags: php, curl

Is there any way to set **CURL_TIMEOUT** to **infinite** ?
I am making a lot of http requests and am receiving  **Gateway Timeout Error** after every **30-50 seconds**.

Can I set it to infinite?

Answer (score 2):

This is done by doing this:

`curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);`

Comment: will it be same for CURL_TIMEOUT (setting 0)? :)

Comment: The CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT is the time cURL waits for the response. CURLOPT_TIMEOUT is the time for the cURL function to execute. So I think you're looking for CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT.

Answer (score 0):

```
 bool set_time_limit ( int $seconds )
set_time_limit (-1 )
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

or change time execute in php.ini

Comment: i am talking about curl

Comment: curl time execute is base on time execute of php